# I am getting a GraphQL query syntax error on a simple query

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

I am getting an error code of 42601: "syntax error at or near ")"

The query itself is very simple:

`query SimilarJobs { similarityScore(skills: ["KS1203W702ND09XHKJR5"]) { score } }`

Here is a screenshot of what's happening:
[image]

I don't see a syntax error myself. Is there something simple that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the query definition on the server end-point?

Comment: Is similarityScore a custom query function? If so, it has a syntax error (in the DB function body).